# Creating a string from several cells in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Probably a newbie question, but is there a good way to bring together / concatenate values from a range of cells and set that as a string?

It's not a small data set, each cell has two characters and the range is usually around A1:YA1, something like 650 cells.

I'm not sure if I'm saying anything correctly, but let's say each cell A1:CU1 had a value that counted from 01 to 99. I'd like to do something like this

```
Sub Sample()

Dim cell_values As String
cell_values = A1:CU1
```

and get a string that would output

> 0102030405060708091011121314...99

Thanks!

Comment: Must read: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you started:

```
Public Sub foo()
    Dim cell_values() As Variant
    cell_values = Sheet1.Range("A1:G1")

    Dim result As String

    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    For r = 1 To UBound(cell_values, 1)
        For c = 1 To UBound(cell_values, 2)
            result = result + cell_values(r, c)
        Next
    Next

    Debug.Print result

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just

```
X = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:CU1"))), vbNullString)
```